# Undesired margin shift - No error and warnings - Underfull \vbox (badness 1521)

Tags: miktex, overleaf

I am almost done with my scientific paper but I have an irritating problem. Some of the margins in my paper are shifted. Please take a look at the attached document. My compilation is free from any errors or warnings. The only message that I am getting is the one below. How can I fix this margin shift? :)

[image]
[image]

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,english,twoside]{extreport}
    % ustawienia marginesów
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{
     a4paper,
     top=25mm,
     inner=35mm,
     outer=25mm,
     bottom=25mm,
    }
% ustawienie interlinii na 1.5
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

% ustawienia paragrafów
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

% zmiana punktowania list na myślniki
\renewcommand\labelitemi{---}

% polskie znaki
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% \usepackage[polish]{babel}
% \usepackage{polski}

% bibliografia
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% listingi i spis listingów
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[center]{caption}
\DeclareCaptionType{code}[Listing][List of listings]
\lstset{breaklines=true,basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize}

% rysunki i spis rysunków
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./img/} }
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

% tabele
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table}
\captionsetup[table]{name=Tabel}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{ %
language=Python,                % choose the language of the code
basicstyle=\footnotesize,       % the size of the fonts that are used for the code
numbers=left,                   % where to put the line-numbers
numberstyle=\footnotesize,      % the size of the fonts that are used for the line-numbers
stepnumber=1,                   % the step between two line-numbers. If it is 1 each line will be numbered
numbersep=5pt,                  % how far the line-numbers are from the code
backgroundcolor=\color{white},  % choose the background color. You must add \usepackage{color}
showspaces=false,               % show spaces adding particular underscores
showstringspaces=false,         % underline spaces within strings
showtabs=false,                 % show tabs within strings adding particular underscores
frame=single,           % adds a frame around the code
tabsize=2,          % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
captionpos=b,           % sets the caption-position to bottom
breaklines=true,        % sets automatic line breaking
breakatwhitespace=false,    % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
escapeinside={\%*}{*)}          % if you want to add a comment within your code
}


% strona tytułowa
\usepackage{pdfpages}

% treść
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\includepdf[pages={1}]{pdf/title_page}
% \null\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\input{tableofcontents}
\input{./Chapters/chapter1}
\input{./Chapters/chapter2}
\input{./Chapters/chapter3}
\input{./Chapters/chapter4}
\input{./Chapters/chapter5}
\input{./Chapters/chapter6}
\input{./Chapters/chapter7}
\input{./Chapters/onsetDetection}

% \section{Wstawianie odniesień do literatury}
% Odniesienie do książki \cite{example_book}. Odniesienie do strony internetowej \cite{example_website}.
\newpage
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\newpage
\listoffigures

\newpage
\listofcodes

\newpage
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{List of tabels}
\listoftables

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi! remove `twoside`? In a two-sides document, the margin shift to allow for the binding of the document.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked like a charm!! :))

Answer (score 1):

The margins are shifted because you use `twoside` as a document option. This option set the margins so that they feel right when looking at a double spread (thanks @Ulrike!) so it shifts the margins between even and odd pages (also, the position of the page number, the running heads, etc., may depend on the even/odd page).

BTW the `underfull` boxes are completely unrelated...

(Probably a duplicate. Let's see if I can find it...)

Comment: the shift is not for the binding, but because in a twoside document the two inner margin are viewed together.  A shift for the binding must be added separatly.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer you're right (of course), thanks!